# How to disable control dynamically in Alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to disable a control this way:

```
YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("disableControl", {'formId':'nss_docs_list', 'fieldId' : "cm:description"})
```

But it doesn't work (and always returns false). Please tell me how to disable a controls on form properly?

Thank you!

Comment: From where you are disabling control? is it in workflow form or document property form?

Comment: a document property form